# Java: optimize hashset for large-scale duplicate detection

Tags: java, optimization, hashset, duplicates

I am working on a project where I am processing a lot of tweets; the goal is to remove duplicates as I process them. I have the tweet IDs, which come in as strings of the format `"166471306949304320"`

I have been using a `HashSet<String>` for this, which works fine for a while. But by the time I get to around 10 million items I am drastically bogged down and eventually get a GC error, presumably from the rehashing. I tried defining a better size/load with

`tweetids = new HashSet<String>(220000,0.80F);`

and that lets it get a little farther, but is still excruciatingly slow (by around 10 million it is taking 3x as long to process). How can I optimize this? Given that I have an approximate idea of how many items should be in the set by the end (in this case, around 20-22 million) should I create a HashSet that rehashes only two or three times, or would the overhead for such a set incur too many time-penalties? Would things work better if I wasn't using a String, or if I define a different HashCode function (which, in this case of a particular instance of a String, I'm not sure how to do)? This portion of the implementation code is below.

```
tweetids = new HashSet<String>(220000,0.80F); // in constructor
duplicates = 0;
...
// In loop: For(each tweet)
String twid = (String) tweet_twitter_data.get("id");
// Check that we have not processed this tweet already
if (!(tweetids.add(twid))){
    duplicates++;
    continue; 
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to your recommendations, I solved it. The problem was the amount of memory required for the hash representations; first, `HashSet<String>` was simply enormous and uncalled for because the `String.hashCode()` is exorbitant for this scale. Next I tried a Trie, but it crashed at just over 1 million entries; reallocating the arrays was problematic. I used a `HashSet<Long>` to better effect and almost made it, but speed decayed and it finally crashed on the last leg of the processing (around 19 million). The solution came with departing from the standard library and using [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). It finished 22 million records a few minutes faster than not checking duplicates at all. Final implementation was simple, and looked like this:

```
import gnu.trove.set.hash.TLongHashSet;
...
    TLongHashSet tweetids; // class variable
... 
    tweetids = new TLongHashSet(23000000,0.80F); // in constructor
...
    // inside for(each record)
    String twid = (String) tweet_twitter_data.get("id");
    if (!(tweetids.add(Long.parseLong(twid)))) {
        duplicates++;
        continue; 
    }
```

Comment: How about treating the ID's as numbers, finding a good base value, and working with differences to that? You could then employ a `HashSet<Long>`, which should outperform strings; you could also use the Trove library to work with primitives.

Comment: Can't you simply increase the size of your heap?

Comment: If you know that the set will eventually contain 22 million items, why don't you create a HashSet with a capacity of 22_000_000 / 0.75 from the start? That would prevent any rehash.

Comment: @JBNizet You mean 22_000_000 / 1.0?

Comment: As far as increasing heap size with something like `java -Xms2gb`, my understanding is that it would be a band-aid against the GC errors but would not help with the dramatic speed degradation.

Comment: @JBNizet I was wondering about that. Yes, I could do that; but isn't there a major processing cost for initially starting with such a large hash? Would the benefits of minimizing rehashes be likely to compensate for that?

Comment: @assylias: no. Unfortunately, the HashSet constructor takes a capacity as argument, and not a size. So passing 22_000_000 would cause a rehash as soon as the 15_500_001th element is added to the set. That's why Guava has Sets.newHashSetWithExpectedSize() which is much more natural.

Comment: @WorldsEndless: in the end, a sufficiently large array will have to be allocated, so why not allocate it from the start, instead of allocating a small one, then a larger one, then yet a larger one, then yet a larger one, and having to rehash everything each time?

Comment: @JBNizet Great question; that's what I'm wondering. Doesn't starting with a humongous array increase the time cost of every standard operation (here, `add`)? I'll give it a try and see what it looks like, though.

Comment: How about a Bloom filter if you can accept a small (controllable) percentage of tweets mis-labeled as duplicates? You could get down to 9.6 bits per tweet at a 1% error rate according to Wikipedia. Would only take up around 25MB for 22 million elements

Comment: @WorldsEndless: I'm pretty sure it doesn't, at least not noticeably. In the end, it's something like calling hashCode, doing a fast binary operation, and accessing an array at a specified index. And adding an element once is faster than adding it three, four of five times due to the rehashes. Also don't forget that the rehashes cause two arrays to be held in memory at the same time.

Comment: @JBNizet Misunderstanding here! I thought your `22m/0.75` meant capacity of 22m and load factor of 0.75f (I now understand you meand 22m *divided by* 0.75), so I replied saying you should use a capacity of 22m and a load factor of 1.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look beyond the Java collections framework. I've done some memory intensive processing and you will face several problems

1. The number of buckets for large hashmaps and hash sets is going to
   cause a lot of overhead (memory). You can influence this by using
   some kind of custom hash function and a modulo of e.g. 50000
2. Strings are represented using 16 bit characters in Java. You can halve that by using utf-8 encoded byte arrays for most scripts.
3. HashMaps are in general quite wasteful data structures and HashSets are basically just a thin wrapper around those.

Given that, take a look at trove or guava for alternatives. Also, your ids look like longs. Those are 64 bit, quite a bit smaller than the string representation.

An alternative you might want to consider is using bloom filters (guava has a decent implementation). A bloom filter would tell you if something is definitely not in a set and with reasonable certainty (less than 100%) if something is contained. That combined with some disk based solution (e.g. database, mapdb, mecached, ...) should work reasonably well. You could buffer up incoming new ids, write them in batches, and use the bloom filter to check if you need to look in the database and thus avoid expensive lookups most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for the existence of Strings, then I would suggest you try using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree#As_a_replacement_for_other_data_structures)(also called a Prefix Tree). The total space used by a Trie should be less than a HashSet, and it's quicker for string lookups.

The main disadvantage is that it can be slower when used from a harddisk as it's loading a tree, not a stored linearly structure like a Hash.  So make sure that it can be held inside of RAM.

The link I gave is a good list of pros/cons of this approach.

*as an aside, the bloom filters suggested by Jilles Van Gurp are great fast prefilters.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? I'm already using a Trie for another portion of the program, but didn't think of making one for this problem. If that works (and it seems obvious now) you will definitely get the answer.

Comment: Ouch. I got a GC overload by only 1 million records. I don't think a Trie is going to work.

Comment: Perhaps I'm implementing it wrong? Mine is just a 10-char recursive array list for chars `0-9 - '0'`. I guess adding to it a million times is bloating the memory usage and demanding reallocation. Do you know a more efficient implementation, given that all I know about my input is that it will be digits 0-9 and 18 digits long?

Comment: I would guess that each Trie node would have 1 char, and an array/list of children.  Not understanding the 10-char recursive array

Comment: Yes, exactly how I'm implementing it. Each node has children[10] and a label at the 19-char point.

Comment: I don't think you should have children[10], that's going to make the Trie always have a branching factor of 10.  the first few nodes might have 10, but as you continue downward through the Trie that will no longer be true.  You should probably only use an array just as big as the number of number of children to save space

Answer (score 0):

Simple, untried and possibly stupid suggestion: Create a Map of Sets, indexed by the first/last N characters of the tweet ID:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> sets = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
String tweetId = "166471306949304320";
sets.put(tweetId.substr(0, 5), new HashSet<String>());
sets.get(tweetId.substr(0, 5)).add(tweetId);
assert(sets.containsKey(tweetId.substr(0, 5)) && sets.get(tweetId.substr(0, 5)).contains(tweetId));
```

That easily lets you keep the maximum size of the hashing space(s) below a reasonable value.

Comment: that adds a lot of operations... this is basically a hash of hashes (+ several equals) with which you wouldnt gain anything